# Android AsynTask method in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am currently working with an arduino that can be controlled using an android phone. I am trying to light up a led from my phone. I tried it and it worked. The problem is that the code was in an activity. am using a tabhost and pageViewer fro the application, the light button in found in a fragment. How to use a fragment to call the method Asyntask and an Onclicklistener for the button in order to light the led.

here's the code the the MainActivity.

```
package com.example.arduinoandroidledtesting;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         /********************************/
        /*    Define all the buttons    */
       /********************************/
       Switch led1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.Led1);
       ToggleButton led2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.Led2);
       Button led3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Led3);

       /*******************************************************/
       /*  Set an onclick/onchange listener for every button  */
      /*******************************************************/

      led1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if (isChecked) {
                  /* Switch is led 1 */
                  new Background_get().execute("led1=1");
              } else {
                  new Background_get().execute("led1=0");
              }
          }
      });


      led2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if(isChecked) {
                  /* Toggle button is led 2 */
                  new Background_get().execute("led2=1");
              } else {
                  new Background_get().execute("led2=0");
              }
          }
      });


      led3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                  /* button is led 3 */
                  new Background_get().execute("led3=1");
              } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                  new Background_get().execute("led3=0");
              }
              return true;
          }
      });
  }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

      /*****************************************************/
    /*  This is a background process for connecting      */
   /*   to the arduino server and sending               */
  /*    the GET request withe the added data           */
 /*****************************************************/

 private class Background_get extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         try {
             /* Change the IP to the IP you set in the arduino sketch */
             URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.177/?" + params[0]);
             HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
             StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
             String inputLine;
             while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                 result.append(inputLine).append("\n");

             in.close();
             connection.disconnect();
             return result.toString();

         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
     }
 }
}
```

please help

Comment: what problem you are facing  ??

Comment: i don't know how to run the code into a fragment

Comment: http://www.mobiledeveloperguide.com/android/using-asynctask-and-fragments.html  this will definitely help you

Comment: `the light button in found in a fragment` what does that mean? Have you already created a fragment ?

Comment: Where is your fragment? and why you don't make your AsyncTask as a public class outside the MainActivity ? so you can call it from any other class.

Comment: in fact i have 5 fragments containing buttons and textviews. One fragment has 1 button for lighting up the led when clicking on it. The code above is an example that i tried and it worked in a different project. but this time , i am trying to insert asyntask method in the fragment containg the button for it to work when clickin on the button

Comment: @abhishek270494 Instead of activity, you want to use fragment right?

Comment: @abhishek270494 So, where you are facing issue?

Comment: an new to android, i don't know how to make it work in a fragment .. can suggest some ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fragment can be like this

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_activity, container, false);      

    Button led3 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Led3);

    led3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            /* button is led 3 */
                new Background_get("led3=1").execute();
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                new Background_get("led3=0").execute();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

You can directly access asynctask class directly

```
 public class Background_get extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String param;

    public Background_get(String param){
        this.param = param;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            /* Change the IP to the IP you set in the arduino sketch */
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.177/?" + param);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            result.append(inputLine).append("\n");

            in.close();
            connection.disconnect();                

        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }

}
```

Comment: i tried this method , but when i click on the button , the appliction stopped working

Comment: Actually, my firewall block this site. You can edit your question & paste there.

Comment: i got it .. its working.. didn't need to use constructor, i called the background class directly ... hey thanks man :D